# MySQL get nearest column from another table

Tags: mysql, subquery, multiple-columns

Im trying to get the title of the nearest Column (Axis) to my main Tables Column from another Table.
Example:

```
Main table with coordinates: Name, x, y
Axis table: title, x, y
```

Now getting the nearest Axis to a Corrdinate:

```
SELECT main.*, 
(SELECT ABS(axis.x-main.x) as min ,axis.title FROM axis WHERE y IS NULL ORDER BY min ASC LIMIT 1) sub_x
FROM corridinates_main
```

This would work. But I cant select two Columns in a Subselect. My Idea would be to use a Subselect for the subselect, but in the sub-subselect I cant access the x-coordinate of the main Table.
Any Idea how to do this?

Comment: Use a `JOIN` instead of a SubQuery

Comment: Could you provide a example? I dont know how I can use a Join for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CROSS JOIN instead of a SubQuery

```
SELECT main.*, Min, Title
FROM corridinates_main
Cross Join
(
    SELECT ABS(axis.x-main.x) as min, axis.title 
    FROM axis 
    WHERE y IS NULL 
    ORDER BY min ASC 
    LIMIT 1
) sub_x
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for me this does not Work. I get the following Error: "#1054 - Unknown column 'main.x' in 'field list' "